# sql azure data sync - transactions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Trying to use SQL Azure data sync for a unidirectional sync between two SQL Azure databases.

Most of the transactions that hit the master database are either read committed or serializable. I am assuming the SQL Azure data sync synchronizes data pertinent to only committed transactions in this scenario?

More importantly, **is SQL Azure data sync robust enough to use in production?** The scenario is simple - unidirectional sync in a master slave configuration. Is there a roadmap for a stable release - it's been in preview since 2011?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.